# connecting c/c++ and python

Tags: c++, python, c, connection, io

What I am trying to do is that I want to read a file using python, and then with the data in the file, create a variable in c/c++(I don't want to read var from the file :) ).

Is this possible?
If this is possible, then how would you do it?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Open the first file in Python, process it and save the results to a second file.

Then open the second file in your C or C++ program and use the data.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually seemed to be the best decision at this moment.

Comment: @DavidGao , If you know Shell Script , you can make it even more simple by running the python file from the shell script and then running the cpp file

Answer (score 7):

Maybe [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/python/doc/) can help.

You could expose a C++ function to your Python script. Something like that:

```
void do_sth_with_processed_data(const std::string& data)
{
  // …
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(do_sth)
{
  def("do_sth_with_processed_data", do_sth_with_processed_data);
}
```

In your Python script you now could have:

```
import do_sth

// … 

do_sth_with_processed_data(my_processed_data) // this calls the c++ function
```

Answer (score 1):

[Swig can generate a Python](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Python.html) interface to C or C++ code for you automatically. Since it wraps constructors you could read the data in Python and then pass it (with a little care) to the constructor of a C++ class for example.